# Advice on database model for ecommerce with custom products

Tags: nhibernate, database-design, model, database-schema

I need some advice on modeling an ecommerce domain.

The client sells two products:

1. Custom art work, the design specified by the customer.
2. Prints of art with a message on the back specified by the customer.

Here is my cut down database model so far.

```
Products:
    Id
    Description
    Price

Orderlines:
    Id
    OrderId
    ProductId

Attributes:
    Id
    Name

OrderAttributes:
    AttributeId
    OrderlineId
    Value
```

The products table will have the 2 products from above.

The order line links the selected product to an order.

The attributes holds the custom field names for each product.

For example the custom artwork product would have the attribute design.

The order attributes links the ordered product to it's customs attributes and has the value.
For example custom artwork product, with an attribute of design, with a value of paint a house.

I would also like to map this database model to code as well using nhibernate.

Is there a better way of modeling this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

The Orderlines table should contain the price (and possibly the description) of the product so that item prices can change without affecting existing orders. Similarly, the Orders table (not shown) should contain customer information (e.g. shipping address) that may change. The data that makes up an order can't change and the easiest approach is to flatten and denormalize it.

The OrderAttributes structure is called an [entity-attribute-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model and it has many drawbacks. In general I recommend avoiding it and adding the needed columns to the Orderlines table. If needed, your application can subclass Product and OrderLine so that a CustomArtWorkProduct creates a CustomArtWorkOrderLine when it's added to an order.

Answer (score 0):

In an object-oriented program relations are expressed as associations.

That is:

- If Product has Orders then Product must have a collection of Orders.
- If an Order is for a Product, the Order must have a property Product.
- and so on.

In object-oriented programming you don't associate by an identifier: you don't need this because this is a different world ruled by hierarchical data.

Honestly, if you follow what I said before, NHibernate will be a very powerful tool as it'll be able of loading objects and properties without your intervention.

Think about "getting all orders of some product": **you're not going to intentionally execute an SQL Join but you're going to access to the `Orders` property of `Product` and NHibernate will translate this access to the database world**.

This is the point of using an OR/M. It's not just "I map tables *as is*". It's about joining two very different worlds: the object-oriented hierarchical world with relational data with no pain.

<strike>Check this very old (2004!) CodeProject article and how it creates the Northwind SQL Server database-based model:</strike>

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8773/NHibernate-in-real-world-applications

Don't pay attention to how maps the model to the database but to the model design.

Check this article, it's more modern than the other one:

- http://litemedia.info/introduction-to-nhibernate

Comment: Thanks, do you have any advice on the database model for product with differing attributes and how to map these?

Comment: @Alex Maybe, but I believe I should know the environment and what's behind your project in order to take a good decision.